# What does this number stand for

Tags: c

I was simply trying out this code which is saw in a tutorial

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a = 34;
    int *ptra = &a;
    printf("%d\n", ptra);

    return 0;
}
```

Here when I run this code I get a number as an output. The number was `6422216`.

What does this number stand for ?

(I was trying to learn pointer arithmetics)

Comment: It stands for the memory location of `a`. Use `%p` to print pointers.

Comment: It represents the (virtual) address or memory location of the variable `a`.

Comment: How far along have you come in your beginners text-book on C? Have you read about pointers yet?

Comment: `ptra` is not of type `int`.  "If any argument is not the
correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined."  Undefined behavior is ... bad.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior of the code sample is actually undefined because you pass a value of type `int *` where `printf` expects an `int` as the argument for conversion `%d`.

The code may be corrected as `printf("%p\n", (void *)ptra);` or possibly `printf("%llu\n", (long long)ptra);`

The value printed is the address of the variable `a`, which is system specific and may change from one run of the program to another, as is the case on OS/X that implements address space randomisation to increase the difficulty for hackers to exploit some program flaws.

To cut a long story short, the answer to your question *What does this number stand for?* is the number is the numeric value of the address of variable `a` which is stored in the pointer `ptr`. Since addresses can be wider than the `int` type, you should use a longer type such as `long long`, preferably unsigned:

```
printf("%llu\n", (long long)ptra);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your program prints out the memory address of where the integer a is stored and I'll explain why but firstly you need to know what the symbols stand for.

`*` - is used to declare a pointer and when placed before a address it will give you what is stored at that address

`&` - will give you the address of the variable written after it

So, first you assign the integer `a` value of `34`

```
int a = 34;
```

Then you create a pointer of a integer called `ptra` and assign it the memory address of where the integer `a` is stored

```
int *ptra = &a;
```

And finally you print the value of `ptra` which is the memory address of where the integer `a` is stored

```
printf("%d\n", ptra);
```

If you would wan to print out the value of a through the integer, then you should replace `ptra` with `*ptra` in the printf function.

Comment: `printf("%d\n", ptra);` has undefined behavior. Either cast `ptra` as `printf("%d\n", (int)ptra);` or use `printf("%p\n", (void *)ptra);`